# Django generate the model from database

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I already have a pre-existing database but now want to use Django. Is there a way to auto generate the model Django needs from my database? For example if I already had a database with tables defined from another application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at the command `inspectdb` in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb). This is a management command to do that, although it doesn't always works, it would be a good starting point.